# Multivariate regression analysis with 7 variables

Tags: regression, multivariate-analysis, finance

I have 7 variables: 1 dependent and 6 independent variable

3 of these independent variables affect 3 of the other independent variables (currency, interest rates, and revenues in respective currencies).

And these 6 variables again affect the dependent variable (total revenues).

Is there a way to use multivariate regression analysis to find how the 3 variables (currencies and interest rates) affect the 3 revenue streams?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you mean, but it sounds more like some sort of path analysis than multivariate regression

Comment: I am supposed to measure the exposures to a company's total revenues. They have three revenue streams with three different exposures. The task is to find their coefficients and then forecast into the short-term.

Comment: Your data seems to be time series. The most popular multivariate time series model is vector autoregression (VAR), also its special case -- the vector error correction (VEC) model. Check them out.

Comment: 1 dependent variable and 6 independent variables: the best approach is multiple regression and not multivariate regression- Kennedy Ekerikevwe

Comment: @user158257 I understand why you would answer this way, due to how the first half of the question is formulated.  However, you are off the mark: the second half of the question makes it clear it concerns *three* dependent variables and three independent variables.